# If an alligator that is 110 inches long weighs 640.94 lbs, what is the residual? If the your predicted weight is 620.13

Tags: regression

Residual: actual weight - predicted weight
640.94 - 620.13 = 20.81, which is the residual, but it shows up as wrong. What did I do wrong?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Have you tried $-20.81?$

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but it says wrong still.

Comment: How do you calculate the 620.13?

Comment: I used the equation above and replaced x with 110.

Comment: Have you tried $20.4$?

Comment: This [tag:self-study] question shows considerable lead-up to the particular question and gives the exact step where there is an issue. I disagree with the closure and have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm your calculations:

```r
d <- data.frame(length = c(126, 71, 106, 105, 84, 97, 125, 124, 79, 114),
                weight = c(727, 504, 654, 541, 484, 555, 656, 645, 434, 698))

cor.test(d$length, d$weight)
# Pearson's product-moment correlation
# 
# data:  d$length and d$weight
# t = 5.3706, df = 8, p-value = 0.0006691
# alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  0.5761193 0.9725971
# sample estimates:
#       cor 
# 0.8847951

m <- lm(weight ~ length, d)
coef(m)
# (Intercept)      length 
# 136.544227     4.396273

pred_m <- as.numeric(predict(m, data.frame(length = 110)))
pred_m
# [1] 620.1343

640.94 - pred_m
# [1] 20.80571
```

With regression coefficients rounded to two decimal places we get a residual of $20.4$ lb:

```r
coef_rounded <- round(coef(m), 2)
coef_rounded
# (Intercept)      length 
# 136.54             4.40 

pred_m_rounded <- as.numeric(coef_rounded %*% c(1, 110))
pred_m_rounded
# [1] 620.54

640.94 - pred_m_rounded
# [1] 20.4
```